# Ajax Request Error when application Deployed to IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've deployed my MVC project application to IIS 7, and it seems to work fine till I execute an ajax request with the following format:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/ControllerName/ActionMethodName",                
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function (data) {
            //Do Something
            }
        });
```

Then It eliminates the application name assigned by IIS and directly access the contoller/actionMethod path from the host!
Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks

Comment: **Never** hardcode urls in ASP.NET MVC. You should always use [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper(v=vs.108).aspx)s to generate them.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how can use the helper?
P.S: the function is inside a JavaScript file, not cshtml file!

Comment: `Url.Action("ActionMethodName", "ControllerName")` will generate the correct url. You can set this value to some `data-` attribute or place into a hidden field. One more option is to set this url to some javascript variable in the page and access this variable in the .js file.